# Issues with REDIS Publish/Subscribe

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I am running REDIS version 5.0.7 (as reported by `redis-server --version`) on Ubuntu 20.04. When I attempt to use REDIS pattern subscribe as explained in [REDIS DOC](https://redis.io/topics/notifications), it does not seem to be work. That is, when I subscribe for any key event (`PSUBSCRIBE *`), I get notifications. But, when I subscribe to a specific pattern (`PSUBSCRIBE stack*`), I don't get any notifications even when I create a new key (`set stack exchange`). I have enabled key events both in the config file (`/etc/redis/redis.conf`) and in command line (`config set notify-keyspace-events KEA`). How to resolve this? Any suggestions? Please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern arguments of PSUBSCRIBE command represent channels not keys. The channel of any *automated* event will contain a prefix. You are not getting any notification using `stack*` pattern because it doesn't contain any of Redis' predefined prefixes.

Try `*stack*` pattern. This would consider the *prefixed channels* as well.